# How to copy a certain node (with children) from a XML with XSLT in Biztalk specifying a custom namespace?

Tags: xslt, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I need to copy a subnode from a XML to a certain node of a new XML in a Biztalk Map using XSLT.

Consider the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="http://not/useful/data/">
    <ns0:notuseful>
        <ns0:foo></ns0:foo>
        <ns0:foo2></ns0:foo2>
        <ns0:blabla></ns0:blabla>
    </ns0:notuseful>
    <ns0:data>
        <ns1:usefulDataList xmlns:ns1="http://useful/data/">
            <ns1:usefulData>
                <ns1:usefulChild1></ns1:usefulChild1>
                <ns1:usefulChild2></ns1:usefulChild2>
                <ns1:usefulChild3></ns1:usefulChild3>
                <ns1:usefulChild4></ns1:usefulChild4>
                <ns1:usefulChild5></ns1:usefulChild5>
            </ns1:usefulData>
        </ns1:usefulDataList>
    </ns0:data>
<ns0:root>
```

What I need is to extract the node called "usefulDataList", so I need to copy it in a new XML like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:root2 xmln:ns2="http://new/xml">
    <ns2:blabla>
        <ns2:stuff />
    </ns2:blabla>
    <ns2:data>
        <ns2:usefulDataList>
            <ns2:usefulData>
                <ns2:usefulChild1></ns2:usefulChild1>
                <ns2:usefulChild2></ns2:usefulChild2>
                <ns2:usefulChild3></ns2:usefulChild3>
                <ns2:usefulChild4></ns2:usefulChild4>
                <ns2:usefulChild5></ns2:usefulChild5>
            </ns2:usefulData>
        </ns2:usefulDataList>
    </ns2:data>
</ns2:root2>
```

This should be done inside a Biztalk Functoid, as you see namespaces from source and target are diferent.

I'm an absolute beginner with XSLT, and I've been doing some tests, but I've something wrong with my XSLT expressions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns2="http://new/xml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template name="testTemplate"  match="//*[local-name() = 'usefulDataList ']">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:usefulDataList " namespace="">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="usefulDataList"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template mode="copy-no-ns" match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd appreciate any tip, with XSLT or Biztalk mapper. I don't like linking a huge amount of fields one by one if I can solve it with a XSLT expression.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware you had a space in `*[local-name() = 'usefulDataList ']"` so that would never match. this works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:ns2="http://new/xml">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <ns2:root>
  <ns2:blabla>
   <ns2:stuff />
  </ns2:blabla>
 <ns2:data>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="//*[local-name() = 'usefulDataList']"/>
 </ns2:data>
</ns2:root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="copy-no-ns" match="*">
 <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name(.)}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're right, this was a sample of a more complex xml and I didn't notice that space. Either way I guess that something is wrong with my template...

Comment: The other main thing wrong with your xslt was `<xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}"> ` which generates an element in the same namespace as the source, see the corrected version in my answer.

Comment: Good point, but my generated xml has a node usefulDataList empty : "<usefulDataList />".

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that last comment. I ran the xsl I posted over your posted input (once I'd made it well formed) and got the result you said you wanted. Do you not get that?

Comment: You're absolutely right, your xslt with my sample works like a charm, but I must be having a mistake using it as an XSLT template in biztalk.

Comment: Got it! My problem was that biztalk was executing another XSLT after my XSLT, so it was cleaning my nodes. Thank you David, I can't vote your solution (I've registered today), I appreciate your help.